# Many-to-many associations with addition attributes

Tags: sequelize.js

I met a issue with Sequelize.
I have 2 models with addition attributes in join table :

```
Project.belongsToMany(models.User, {
  foreignKey: 'projectId',
  as: 'users',
  through: models.ProjectUser
});

User.belongsToMany(models.Project, {
  foreignKey: 'userId',
  as: 'projects',
  through: models.ProjectUser
});

module.exports = (sequelize, DataTypes) => {
  const ProjectUser = sequelize.define('ProjectUser', {
    leader: DataTypes.BOOLEAN,
    manager: DataTypes.BOOLEAN
  }, {});
  ProjectUser.associate = function(models) {
    // associations can be defined here
  };
  return ProjectUser;
};
```

In my controller, I use setUsers([]) to make sure there is no duplicate records in 1 project :

```
if (updateProject.users.length !== 0) {
  updatedProject.setUsers([]);
  updateProject.users.forEach(user => {
    updatedProject.addUser(user.userId, { through: { leader: user.leader, manager: user.manager }});
});
```

Issue happens when I insert new records with same id as previous. For example :

```
[ { userId: 1, leader: 0, manager: 0 },
  { userId: 2, leader: 1, manager: 1 } ]
```

then

```
[ { userId: 1, leader: 0, manager: 0 },
  { userId: 2, leader: 1, manager: 1 },
  { userId: 3, leader: 0, manager: 0 } ]
```

and result is only userId 3 in join table. From terminal :

```
Executing (default): DELETE FROM `ProjectUsers` WHERE `projectId` = 1 AND `userId` IN (1, 2)
Executing (default): UPDATE `ProjectUsers` SET `leader`=?,`manager`=?,`updatedAt`=? WHERE `projectId` = ? AND `userId` = ?
Executing (default): UPDATE `ProjectUsers` SET `leader`=?,`manager`=?,`updatedAt`=? WHERE `projectId` = ? AND `userId` = ?
Executing (default): INSERT INTO `ProjectUsers` (`leader`,`manager`,`createdAt`,`updatedAt`,`projectId`,`userId`) VALUES (false,false,'2019-07-04 17:57:29','2019-07-04 17:57:29',1,3);
```

So, am I wrong when using setUsers([]) ?

Comment: `make sure there is no duplicate records`, can you make clear on this?
Does it mean no duplicated combination for `userId`, `leader` and `manager`?

Comment: @이준형 Yeah, that's. But I dont know how to edit old records. I know only setUsers(), addUser(), addUsers() from [Belongs-To-Many associations](http://docs.sequelizejs.com/manual/associations.html#belongs-to-many-associations), so my solution is removing all users of project, then add them again.

Comment: Ok, MySQL provides thing called unique constraint over multiple columns. It means you can set that on userId, leader and manager and after that record with same combination of input will be banned and Sequelize will throw duplicated entry error. Go checkout the [doc](http://docs.sequelizejs.com/manual/models-definition.html).

Comment: Aw, sorry, I've misunderstood. My purpose is only 1 leader and 1 manager for each project. And if 1 user is leader or manager or both, there's no more record of that user. So [ { userId: 1, leader: 0, manager: 0 }, { userId: 1, leader: 1, manager: 1 } ] is invalid.

Comment: Uhm, sorry for my bad English and I didn't describe cleary. I think we have  X-Y problem here. My code work well when there's no records. And the problem is setUsers([]) delete both old records and new records has same { projectId, userId } with old records instead of deleteing only old records.

Comment: I think it’s too complicated so that it’s better to query first and then either accept or reject new record. setUsers will not gonna solve your problem, since all it does is just updating userId in your project table.

Comment: Oh, thanks for helping. I found a solution is making leader and manager as project's attributes, so there's no addition attributes and I can use setUser([user_array]) easily.